# New HDD in 19.10: Where is 7MiB/s constant write activity coming from?

Tags: mount, disk, io

I just added a brand new 4TB spinning disk to my system, created one ext4 partition on it, labeled it HDD4 and mounted it exactly like /mnt/HDD (which works perfectly).  It is /dev/sdc1.
Here is the complete fstab:

```
LABEL=OS    /           ext4    errors=remount-ro           0   1
/swapfile   none        swap    sw                          0   0
LABEL=HDD   /mnt/HDD    ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro  0   2
LABEL=HDD4  /mnt/HDD4   ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro  0   2
//10.0.0.88/Users   /mnt/M6800  cifs noauto,iocharset=utf8,
                    credentials=/home/dean/.cifs_credentials 0 0
```

As soon as I issue the mount command, "nmon" shows constant 7MiB/sec write activity to that device, even though there are no files on it, "fatrace" shows nothing, and there is nothing in syslog or dmesg indicating any activity or errors at all, and the system is idle.
As soon as I issue a umount command the activity goes away (obviously).  As soon as I reissue the mount command, the constant 7MiB/sec write activity resumes.  "df /mnt/HDD4" shows "used" space not increasing.

```
dean/ 86 >df /mnt/HDD4
Filesystem      1K-blocks  Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1      3844660232 69636 3649223380   1% /mnt/HDD4
dean/ 87 >
```

Where else should I look to track this down? thanks...
forgot to mention the system is xubuntu 19.10 amd64:

```
uname -a
Linux CUDA1 5.3.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 09:22:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[nmon-screen-capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq5J6.png)

Comment: At first I would give `iotop` a try. To know what exactly is using your 7MiB/s and you'll be able to dig deeper.

Comment: thank you LupusE. I installed iotop as you suggested and noticed a process "ext4lazyinit" which I didn't receognize so I googled it and learned that the kernel is still initializing the drive. I'll give it some time to complete and update on status .

Comment: @user3071462 Please write this up as an answer and give it the green checkmark so others will know it solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [LupusE](https://askubuntu.com/users/933610/lupuse)'s suggestion I installed `iotop` and noticed a process "ext4lazyinit" which I didn't recognize so I googled it and learned that the kernel is still initializing the drive.  After 4 hours IO droppped to zero and the ext4lazyinit process is gone.